# AWS Command Line Interface Unable to Locate Credentials - Special Permissions

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, command-line-interface

Okay, so I've encountered an insanely frustrating problem while trying to reach an AWS S3 Bucket through AWS CLI via the command prompt in Windows 7. The AWS CLI is "unable to locate credentials" a.k.a. the config.txt file @ `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config.txt`.

I've tried pathing to it by creating the AWS_CONFIG_FILE environmental variable in ControlPanel>System>AdvancedSystemSettings>EnvironmentalVariables, but no dice. I've also tried all of the above on another Win7 machine. Again, no dice.

What could I be missing here. Are there any special permission that need to be set for AWS CLI to accest config.txt? Help, before I poke my own eyes out!

The contents of config.txt, in case you're interested, are:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = key id here
aws_secret_access_key = key here
region = us-east-1
```

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\config

Comment: You're right, but I mis-wrote that in the explanation with "<" and ">" around USERNAME (now edited). Had no idea that it would remove the text all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so the config file cannot be a text file (.txt). You should create the file in CMD, and it should be a generic file w/o any extension.

Comment: How did you do this ?

Comment: In the file explorer. Just change the file extension the same way you would the name of the file.

Answer (score 43):

There is a another way to configure aws credentials while using command line tool.
You can pass credentials using windows command instead of passing through file.
Execute below command from windows command prompt

```
aws configure
```

It prompt you to enter below things

```
AWS Access key ID:
AWS secrete key ID:
Default region Name:
Default output Format:
```

See this video tutorial: https://youtu.be/hhXj8lM_jBs

Comment: Was facing same issue. It turned out to be that i had no accesskey and secret got created. Followed steps mentioned in aws link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey and then Tried same in My mac machine as mentioned in youtube link. It Worked!!. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A couple of points on this as I had similar problems whilst trying to perform an S3 sync.

My findings were as follows.

1. Remove the spaces between hte `=` and the key value pair (see example below).
2. The OP has specified a `[default]` section in their example, but I got the same error when I had removed this section as I did not think it was needed so it's worth nothing this is needed.

I then reformed my file as follows and it worked...

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****
region=eu-west-2

[deployment-profile]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****
region=eu-west-2
```

3. I had to include a blank line at the bottom of my `credentials` file.

Just posting this really as I struggled for a few hours with vague messages from AWS and these were the solutions that worked for me. Hope that it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Your solution worked when everything else failed..

Answer (score 2):

If like me you have a custom IAM user in your credentials file rather than 'default', try setting the `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` env variable to the name of your IAM user, and then running commands.

```
[user1]
ACCESS_KEY=
SECRET_KEY=
```

```
set AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=user1
aws <command>
```

Alternatively you can specify the `--profile` variable each time you use the cli:

```
aws <command> --profile user1
```